# Bootstrap collapse should be open in Desktop but closed in Mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Does someone know how I can have a collapse open in Desktop and closed in Mobile?
Would it be possible with Bootstrap only?

Desktop:
[image]

Mobile:

Here the Content should be shown only if you click on the Title of each group
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am newbie but maybe you can try mediaQuery with css display:none or hidden classes

Comment: I know this method. I am trying to get around this with only using Bootstrap predefined classes if possible.